# Keep getting "identifier expected" and "; expected" error messages

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a high score system for my game in unity and am not really sure on how to do that, but I tried this code nonetheless and I keep receiving error messages.

I have tried to search up these errors but since I am quite new to unity and coding in general none of the solutions there make sense to me.

```
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
public Text highScore;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
    scoreText = scoreText.int.Parse;

    if (scoreText > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0)) ;
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", scoreText);
        highScore.text = scoreText.ToString;
    }
```

These are the error messages that show up

Assets\Score.cs(15,31): error CS1001: Identifier expected

Assets\Score.cs(15,31): error CS1002: ; expected

Comment: How does this `scoreText = scoreText.int.Parse;` work?

Comment: sorry i dont know i got it off https://stackify.com/convert-csharp-string-int/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have presently won't work. It would be nice  if you could learn the basics syntax of C# to possibly avoid problems like this.

`Text` is a class and `scoreText` in this case is an instance of the `Text` class. You can't just do this:

```
scoreText = scoreText.int.Parse;
```

Unless of course, `scoreText.int.Parse` (doesn't work though) returns a `Text`.

I think what you're trying to do is to get the player's position and convert to int, so you could save the value using `PlayerPrefs`.

You can simply create an int variable.

```
private int _score;
```

Then use like this:

```
_score=int.Parse(scoreText.text);
```

You can the save using `PlayerPrefs`.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", _score);
```

I hope this helps.

There is also an error on this line:

```
highScore.text = scoreText.ToString;
```

Should be :

```
highScore.text = scoreText.ToString();
```

Because `ToString()` is a method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after the If condition.

### Code:

```
void Update()
{
scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
// scoreText = scoreText.int.Parse;

if (scoreText > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0)) 
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", scoreText);
    highScore.text = scoreText.ToString();
}
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: Why do you have this line? 
scoreText = scoreText.int.Parse;

Comment: It gives me this error is i dont have it Assets\Score.cs(20,40): error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: ToString is a method while you are trying to use it as a property.


    highScore.text = scoreText.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
public Text highScore;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
    int scoreTextNumber = int.Parse(scoreText.text);

    if (scoreText > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0)) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", scoreTextNumber);
        highScore.text = scoreTextNumber.ToString("0");
    }
```